Is this graph planar?
The PlanarGraph command displays graphs using a planar embedding if possible.
Thus, quite expectingly
PlanarGraph[HypercubeGraph[4]]
(*is not a planar graph, input returned*)

Also, as expected HypercubeGraph[3] is planar
PlanarGraph[HypercubeGraph[3]]


But I do not understand this output:
PlanarGraph[NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3]]


Somehow I doubt that this graph is planar. At least I see edge crossings. Is it expected behavior?

It is planar.  Draw a straight line along ten nodes.  Then alternate the distance = 2 arches... above, below, above, below... the horizontal.  Then add the remaining links.

@DavidG.Stork Ok, I see. But shouldn't PlanarGraph provide planar layout? This layout is not manifestly planar.


GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding" or GraphLayout ->"TutteEmbedding"

PlanarGraph[NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3], 
   GraphLayout -> #] & /@ {"PlanarEmbedding", "TutteEmbedding"}



Ok, thank you. According to the documentation, PlanarGraphdisplays the graph using a planar embedding if possible. So, it a simple bug of PlanarGraph, am I right?

This is a very interesting bug! The key difference between your HypercubeGraph[3] and NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3] is that the first one comes without predefined VertexCoordinates, while the second one has a fixed layout:
Options[HypercubeGraph[3]]
(* {} *)

Options[NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3]]
(* {GraphLayout -> "LinearEmbedding", 
    VertexCoordinates -> {{1., 0}, {2., 0}, {3., 0}, {4., 0}, {5., 0}, 
     {6., 0}, {7., 0}, {8., 0}, {9., 0}, {10., 0}}} *)

If you give to PlanarGraph a graph with fixed VertexCoordinates, it will first try to determine whether your layout is already a valid planar embedding. It will do this internally using GraphComputation`PlanarGraphDump`validPlanarEmbeddingQ. However, the checking is done with the following code:
Region`Mesh`IntersectionFreeSegmentsQ[Line @ edges,
    "Ignore" -> {
        "EndPointsTouching", "EndPointTouchingSegment", "PointTouchesEndPoint", 
        "PointTouchesSegment", "PointsOverlap", "SegmentsOverlap"
    }
]

Let's use it on your graph:
With[{g = NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3]}, 
 GraphComputation`PlanarGraphDump`validPlanarEmbeddingQ[g,
  VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g]]]
(* True *)

Do you see the problem? It doesn't take into consideration the shape of the edges, it just considers them as lines! So roughly speaking, it looks at the following image:
With[{g = NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3]}, 
 Graph[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"]]


and decides it's a valid planar embedding (note that overlapping lines are ignored), hence it will not do any further processing on it, and return the same input graph.
A simple solution is therefore to remove vertex coordinates from your initial graph.
NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3, VertexCoordinates -> Automatic]
(* or GraphComputation`BareGraph[NearestNeighborGraph[Range[10], 3]] *)
PlanarGraph[%]



It is amazing that you managed to find this out! So, this means that knowing VertexCoordinates disables the planarity check. I think one might even construct a non-planar graph with vertices on the line that will manifestly fail in PlanarGraph

@yarchik, well, this I do not think can happen, luckily :) For example: PlanarGraph@  CompleteGraph[5, VertexCoordinates -> Table[{i, 0}, {i, 5}]] will correctly complain that the graph is not planar, because it will check it first using PlanarGraphQ which uses some internal correct algorithm to determine whether it is planar or not. It is just this auxilliary validPlanarEmbeddingQ that verifies the embedding which is problematic, and indeed gives True in this case:

With[{g = CompleteGraph[5, VertexCoordinates -> Table[{i, 0}, {i, 5}]]}, GraphComputation`PlanarGraphDump`validPlanarEmbeddingQ[g, VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g]]]
